# Weirdly getting "! Argument of \@tempa has an extra }" error in a really simple file

Tags: floats

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat, manuscript=article]{achemso}

\author{XX}
\affiliation{Department of Physics,}

\title[test]
{test}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

This really simple latex file gives me the following error. I have tried changing the style of the document to article and the problem persists. I've googled the errors, and it doesn't seem that I'm missing a "}" or "\end{.}" statement anywhere. I'm really confused.

** Updated **

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.8.31)  1 SEP 2020 03:15
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ach
emso/achemso.cls"
Document Class: achemso 2020-05-27 v3.13a Submission to ACS journals

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/bas
e/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/bas
e/size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/xke
yval/xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic/x
keyval/xkeyval.tex"
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic/x
keyval/xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic/x
keyval/keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count175
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\acs@bib@file=\write3
\c@bibnote=\count176

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/geo
metry/geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic/i
ftex/ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic/i
ftex/iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count177
\Gm@cntv=\count178
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count179
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen135
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen136
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen137
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen138
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen139
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen140
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen141
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen142
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/geo
metry/geometry.cfg"))
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cap
tion/caption.sty"
Package: caption 2020/05/30 v3.4k Customizing captions (AR)

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cap
tion/caption3.sty"
Package: caption3 2020/05/30 v1.12 caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 61.
\captionmargin=\dimen143
\captionmargin@=\dimen144
\captionwidth=\dimen145
\caption@tempdima=\dimen146
\caption@indent=\dimen147
\caption@parindent=\dimen148
\caption@hangindent=\dimen149
Package caption Info: Standard document class detected.
)
\c@caption@flags=\count180
\c@continuedfloat=\count181
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/flo
at/float.sty"
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count182
\float@exts=\toks18
\float@box=\box45
\@float@everytoks=\toks19
\@floatcapt=\box46
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/gra
phics/graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/gra
phics/graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/gra
phics/trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/gra
phics-cfg/graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/gra
phics-def/pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen150
\Gin@req@width=\dimen151
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/set
space/setspace.sty"
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/url
/url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\acs@author@cnt=\count183
\acs@affil@cnt=\count184
\acs@affil@alt@cnt=\count185
\acs@footnote@cnt=\count186
\acs@affil@marker@cnt=\count187
\acs@space@pre@title=\skip49
\acs@space@post@title=\skip50
\acs@space@post@author=\skip51
\acs@space@post@address=\skip52
\acs@space@post@email=\skip53
\acs@maketitle@width=\skip54
\@float@every@scheme=\toks20
\c@scheme=\count188
\@float@every@chart=\toks21
\c@chart=\count189
\@float@every@graph=\toks22
\c@graph=\count190
\@float@every@table=\toks23
\acs@collect@toks=\toks24
\acs@collect@empty@toks=\toks25
\acs@tocentry@height=\skip55
\acs@tocentry@width=\skip56

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ach
emso/achemso-jacsat.cfg"
File: achemso-jacsat.cfg 2020-05-27 v3.13a achemso configuration: J. Am. Chem. 
Soc.
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/nat
bib/natbib.sty"
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip57
\bibsep=\skip58
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count191
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ach
emso/natmove.sty"
Package: natmove 2010/01/15 v1.1a Automatic citation moving with natbib
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/mci
teplus/mciteplus.sty"
Package: mciteplus 2013/09/13 v1.2 enhanced mcite
\@mcitetmptoksA=\toks26
\@mcitetmpdima=\dimen152
\@mcitetmpdimb=\dimen153
\@mcitetmpcnta=\count192
\@mcitetmpcntb=\count193
\c@mcitebibitemcount=\count194
\c@mcitesubitemcount=\count195

** mciteplus: Detected natbib.sty. Invoking hooks.
))
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/l3b
ackend/l3backend-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-18 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count196
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
\openout3 = `acs-test.bib'.


*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.2698pt, 469.75539pt, 72.2698pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.2698pt, 650.43037pt, 72.2698pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75539pt
* \textheight=650.43037pt
* \oddsidemargin=-0.00018pt
* \evensidemargin=-0.00018pt
* \topmargin=-37.00018pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=44.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.

("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/context/b
ase/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count197
\scratchdimen=\dimen154
\scratchbox=\box48
\nofMPsegments=\count198
\nofMParguments=\count199
\everyMPshowfont=\toks27
\MPscratchCnt=\count266
\MPscratchDim=\dimen155
\MPnumerator=\count267
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count268
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks28
)
("/Users/swan.h/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/eps
topdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)

Class achemso Warning: No e-mail given:
(achemso)              at lest one author must have a contact e-mail on input l
ine 13.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 13.
Runaway argument?
"example-image-a.png" \edef \Gin@ext {\Gin@sepdefault \filename@ext }\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.19 
     
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 16 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 \end{document}
                   
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

(test.aux)
! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
\enddocument ... \endgroup \deadcycles \z@ \@@end 
                                                  
l.21 \end{document}
                   
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 16 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 \end{document}
                   
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

)
! Emergency stop.
<*> ./test.tex
              
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4183 strings out of 482725
 68831 string characters out of 2946709
 302690 words of memory out of 3000000
 19931 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 537228 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 63i,3n,100p,229b,282s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: The actual first error given by the document you have there is "Undefined control sequence" for `\affiliation`. Can you make sure that what you quote in the question is an actual complete document that yields that error?

Comment: You are missing `\documentclass` sand `\usepackage{graphicx}` statements in your MWE. The underscores in your image file names may be the cause of the error.

Comment: Why do you encase `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{rmsd_ref_res_sys2.png}` in curly braces?

Comment: @pst I have updated the errors.

Comment: @Mico that's the format of using includegraphics, no?

Comment: @Andrew I forgot to paste the document class, but I added the graphicx package and the error is still there.

Comment: @new_latex_user - No. Wrapping `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{rmsd_ref_res_sys2.png}` in curly braces creates needless code clutter at best -- and could do worse.

Comment: @Mico actually, you're right. I took out the curly braces.

Comment: So now the document yields no error, right? So in your editing you have removed whatever it was that caused the error.

Comment: @pst I'm still getting the same error "! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete." and the other errors in the log files above.

Comment: show the complete log-file until the error. And try if you can replace in your example the graphic with `example-image-a.png`, then your code can be tested by others too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer updated the png and part of the log file that pertains to the error.

Comment: I wrote "show the complete log-file until the error". You don't know what is important, so please show what I say and not what you think you should show.

Comment: The example code as now given in the question compiles fine for me (over TeX Live 2020).  Have you tried deleting the auxiliary files created by TeX (`*.aux`, `*.bib` and so on) since editing the code to this current version?  Sometimes an error can persist in the auxiliary files.

Comment: For me this compiles without problem. I suspect you need to update something. Supplying the full log file as Ulrike suggests would help. My log file shows `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)`, `achemso 2020-07-21 v3.13b`, `article 2019/12/20 v1.4l`, ...

Comment: It compiles fine on Ubuntu 18.04 too, which is TeXLive 2017 with some packages from 2018. achemso is from 2018/02/05

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I misunderstood. I have pasted the whole log file.

Comment: @Andrew, full log file updated

Comment: Your `MWE` working fine for me without doing any modification, based on your `.log` file, understood that you are using little bit older version of `MiTeX`, please update it and check...

Comment: In terms of packages, you have old versions of `graphicx`and `graphics` (both from 2017) and `caption` (actually `caption3`; your version is from May 2020 but given your error message and the fact that a minor patch soon followed the version you have this is the most likely culprit). It might be worth upgrading these three packages to see if that makes a difference.